# Looking how to Implement Document Conversion in MOSS 2007

Tags: ms-word, sharepoint-2007, pdf-generation, document

We've been tasked with creating a MOSS workflow that on it's final step will convert a document (most likely from word 2003 or 2007) to PDF and watermark it with the current date.

So far I haven't seen a definitive way to do this.  Have looked at using the MS Word Interop dlls, but we will not be installing Word (or Office) onto the server - so that's really not doable.  Another option I've looked at is using Aspose dll libraries for conversion.

From a topology standpoint, wondering if using one server exclusively for document conversion is a good way to implement this. (I've read some info that recommends this approach for larger organizations).

If anyone - who has preferable done this sort of thing, can give me some pointers or best practices on this I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would think that starting with one server is the best way to go. Then, just monitor the workload on the machine and if it gets to be too much for one, pop another in there. That's the beauty of MOSS.